# What is the max value of a double in Android?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, double, max

I created a small game that uses big numbers on Unity.
It displays it as "aa, ab, ac,..., az, ba, ..." and so on.
Used doubles for it. I think I went as far as "ds"s.
The problem is, when I built the game for Android and ran it on my phone, it only goes as far as (I think) "aj"s. Why?

What is the max value of a double in Android, and is there any way to exceed it?

Edit: Added screenshots from pc and android.
This is android:
[image: Android]
And this is on pc:
[image: Pc]

Answer (score 0):

From [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html)

Constant Value: 1.7976931348623157E308

Comment: Hi.  
1 ds = 1E + 300  
So it's normal on pc. I get that too. But in android for some reason, it stops at somewhere at 1E+15's which is "ak"s.

Comment: So, you might be actually right. Maybe there is a problem with my phone? :/

Comment: Nope, it's like this in all the android devices. Even in emulators!